# Empty Object Issue when Retrieving Nested Data using Endpoints

Tags: json, postman

I have encountered an issue while testing my endpoints. The primary code I have implemented thus far is the db.json file in my React project, and during testing, I observed that when I try to retrieve nested objects, I receive an empty object as the response.

For instance, when accessing the endpoint "walls/1," I receive the expected data, but when attempting to access "walls/1/title" or "walls/1/stations," the response returns an empty object.

I have shared the relevant code and JSON file for reference on GitHub: https://github.com/antwoinegriggs/Staffing-Tool/blob/main/db.json . I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions to help resolve this issue and enable successful retrieval of nested objects in my project.

```
{
  "walls": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Wall 201",
      "stations": [
        {
          "id": "201-1",
          "name": "Pack 1",
          "isOccupied": false
        },
        {
          "id": "201-2",
          "name": "Pack 2",
          "isOccupied": false
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Wall 202",
      "stations": [
        {
          "id": "202-1",
          "name": "Pack 1",
          "isOccupied": false
        },
        {
          "id": "202-2",
          "name": "Pack 2",
          "isOccupied": false
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I have tried rewriting my db.json file and I have tested using Postman with from while running JSON server in terminal